# Installing CUDA 7.5 on Kubuntu 15.10 x64

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, cuda

I'm having issues installing on Kubuntu 15.10 x64, with two Nvidia GTX 690 cards.

I tried:

```
# Install Nvidia drivers
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340 nvidia-prime # http://askubuntu.com/a/698736/44876
```

reboot

I checked that Nvidia drivers were correctly installed:

```
f@f-Aurora-R4:~$ nvidia-smi
Mon Nov 16 11:07:40 2015     
+------------------------------------------------------+                     
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.93     Driver Version: 340.93      |                    
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name     Persistence-M| Bus-Id       Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|       Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 690  Off  | 0000:04:00.0     N/A |               N/A |
| 30%   38C P8  N/A /  N/A |    8MiB /  2047MiB |   N/A     Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 690  Off  | 0000:05:00.0     N/A |               N/A |
| 35%   49C P0  N/A /  N/A |    101MiB /  2047MiB |     N/A     Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                            GPU Memory |
|  GPU      PID  Process name                                   Usage   |
|=============================================================================|
|   0           Not Supported                                               |
|   1           Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Since the Nvidia drivers seemed correctly installed, I then proceed to install the Nvidia CUDA toolkit:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Then I rebooted, and tried to install CUDA:

```
# Install cuda
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1504/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1504_7.5-18_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1504_7.5-18_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

reboot

This resulted in Nvidia drivers not working anymore (no more GUI at startup). What did I do wrong?

The Kubuntu installation was a fresh one, I've only done `sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get upgrade` on it.